# check compiler with break point

Tags: c#

When I tried to focus on compiler in code, I made break point on code.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    using (SqlConnection Con = Connection.GetConnection())
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["Category_Id"] != null &&
            DDlProductFamily.SelectedIndex < 0)
        {
            SqlCommand Com = new SqlCommand("SelectAllCtageories_Front", Con);
            Com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Com.Parameters.Add(Parameter.NewInt(
                "@Category_Id", Request.QueryString["Category_Id"]));

            SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(Com);
            DA.Fill(dt);
            DataList1.DataSource = dt;
            DataList1.DataBind();
        }
```

But I cannot check condition although I had the value of query string.

Comment: -1 I don't understand what you're saying or asking.

Comment: ... Are you asking how to see the value of `Request.QueryString["Category_Id"]` when you're at a breakpoint?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question here.

Comment: I asked that I had query string also condition of if right but code didn't give any value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `F10` and `F11` to step through the code once your breakpoint is hit.

If you want to see values of the variables then you can hover over them or `right-click` and `add watch` or `add quick watch`.

If you want to check if your condition is `true` or `false` then **select the whole condition** right click and select one of the options mentioned above.

I don't understand your question. But you would like [Sarah Ford's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you've placed a breakpoint somewhere inside the `if (Request.QueryString["Category_Id"] != null && DDlProductFamily.SelectedIndex < 0)` statement, and when you debug your application, your breakpoint is never hit. Am I right?

A few things to check, then.

1. Make sure your solution is set to Debug mode. This should be on the standard Visual Studio toolbar, as a dropdown. You've probably done this already, but no harm in making sure.
2. Place the breakpoint on the if statement itself, and add watches to the two conditions. My guess is that if, as you say, the query result is a non-null value, then that can only mean that `DDlProductFamily.SelectedIndex < 0` evaluates to false.
3. Actually, it's probably worth making sure that `IsPostBack` is also true, to make sure you're actually entering this code block. You could either stick breakpoints on every line you're interested in, or as [TheMachineCharmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662600/check-compiler-with-break-point/2662653#2662653) suggests, you could step through each line using F10.

Based on the limited information in your question, my best guess is that either `DDlProductFamily.SelectedIndex` is less than 0, or `IsPostBack` is false.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I forgot mentioned that code in 
 protected void DataList1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
}